# Is saying Salam or facing towards the grave of Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) and greeting him Shirk?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, shirk, greetings, grave

I am asking so because a lot of Muslims in [Masjid Al Nabawi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Masjid_an-Nabawi) in Madina face to the grave of Prophet Muhammad (PBUH)  say Salam directly to prophet or read some Du'a:

> السَّلامُ عَلَیکَ یا رَسول الله

But some people prevent them to do so (specially several years ago - they are more tolerate now I feel) and say:

- Prophet is passed away and he is no longer alive to hear us or reply our Salam.
- We should only ask Allah. Asking something from prophet is Shirk.
- We should face only towards Qibla. Facing towards the grave of prophet is Haram.

For sure the people who ask prophet something - like their forgiveness - don't think prophet is God or doing something independent of Allah. In fact *they ask him to ask Allah something on behalf of them, because he has more reputation near Allah*.

So is saying Salam to prophet Muhammad, asking him something, or facing towards his grave Shirk or Haram? The answers of both Sunni and Shia brothers/sisters are more than welcome.

Comment: You may find good info regarding your question [on this page](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2519/584) brother.

Answer (score 2):

- Saluting the Prophet (saaw) at his grave is not shirk. In fact, it is recommended.
- Asking him for help or money or pregnancy or even forgiveness is shirk.
- You are required to face Qibla only during prayers. Other than that, face anywhere you like.

Here is a fatwa from Bin Baz regarding this issue (in Arabic):
http://www.binbaz.org.sa/mat/19164

Answer (score 2):

It's also good to say that the shaf'a is being asked from its real owner Allah subhnih wo t'ala , He is the real owner of the shafa'a , and no one can make shafa'a  unless Allah  subhnih  wo t'ala  allow him .

Prophet never tought people to ask shafa'a from him

[what is the meaning shafa'ah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7060/what-is-the-meaning-of-shafaah-sunni-view)

[Tafser of meaning of اية الكرسي](http://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=51&ID=144)

Answer (score 2):

> face to the grave of prophet Muhammad (PBUH) say Salam directly to prophet

Not only the prophet's(pbuh) but to say the following in your inner self when ever you come across any grave(Muslim) is highly recommended.

> **Peace be upon the inhabitants of the graves, believers and Muslims. May Allaah have mercy upon those who have gone ahead of us and those who come later on, and verily we will, Insha’Allaah, join you.** (Thirmidi, Janaaiz 58-59 narrated by Ibn-i Abbas)

The above Hadith which I quoted is not to be mistaken. Our intention is to be just wishing peace on the people in the graves including Prophet(pbuh), but not wishing them as though you wish a person you just met saying Assalamu Alaikum.

> Prophet is passed away and he is no longer alive to hear us or reply our Salam.
>
> Surely **you do not make the dead to hear**, and you do not make the deaf to hear the call when they go back retreating. (Qur'an 27:80)

So, Qur'an literally says so. So we must not be having any doubt about it.

> We should only ask Allah. Asking something from prophet is Shirk.

**Yes.** Because you yourself said,

> You (Alone) we worship, and you (Alone) we ask for help(Qur'an 1:5)

(Note: In terms of Ghaib(unseen) we ask only to Allah , I'm not talking about asking your friend to get a cup of coffee)

> We should face only towards Qibla. Facing towards the grave of prophet is Haram.

You need not face only towards Qibla and you should not face only towards the grave of Prophet(pbuh). As I said, intention matters, not the direction.

More over,

> they ask him to ask Allah something on behalf of them, because he has more reputation near Allah.

The concept of Prophet(pbuh) being given the power to intercede on our behalf is mistakenly deduced to the fore mentioned belief. It is on the day of Judgement, when Prophet (pbuh) *because he has more reputation near Allah* will be able to intercede as Allah permits. And Prophet(pbuh) will start interceding about those who are closer to him on that day. So, asking Prophet(pbuh) directly doesn't make you get closer to him, but doing so keeps you far away from him. **To get closer**, you need to **ask Allah to send blessings on him(Durood)**. That is the prescribed way.

You don't require a medium today to ask forgiveness, because, the creator says

> And indeed We have created man, and We know what his ownself whispers to him. And We are nearer to him than his jugular vein. (Qur'an 50:16)
>
> And seek Forgiveness of Allah. Verily, Allah is Oft-Forgiving, Most-Merciful. (Qur'an 73:20)

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score 2):

Salaams 
Its a shame that today we have lost touch with the spiritual side of islam. In chapter 2 of the holy Quran Allah states verse 2 , the ones that believe in the unseen.
Then Allah says
وَلَا تَحْسَبَنَّ الَّذِينَ قُتِلُوا فِي سَبِيلِ اللَّهِ أَمْوَاتًا ۚ بَلْ أَحْيَاءٌ عِنْدَ رَبِّهِمْ يُرْزَقُونَ

Think not of those who are killed in the Way of Allah as dead. Nay, they are alive, with their Lord, and they have provision.  (Aali Imran 3:169)

So if you only look at this material world than yes you will not be able to comprehend the next world (unseen)
We need to read the Quran with greater attention because all the answers lie within it.
This whole shirk business regarding the Graves is a new innovation just look at the history of islam and you will see the companions used to visit the Graves regularly as per instructions of the Prophet Muhammed PBUH.

Answer (score 0):

I read on this page somewhere on top that 'The prophet is dead and not alive in his grave'. Just to clarify this point every prophet are alive in their grave and when you're near the grave not only they can hear  you but they can also see you and if you say salaam to them, they answer your salaam as well. Apart from phrophets and the pious people who are alive in their grave... rest us of are totaly dead just the our remaining bones left.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum , sister /brother,

there is nothing wrong or shirk in saying salam to prophet Muhammad s.a.w ( be peace upon him ) even Allah swt has recommended everyone to send durood and salaam to prophet Muhammed s.a.w and basically everyone an ordinary human being who is dead even listens and reply to the salam but we cant hear it then prophet Muhammad is the messenger of Allah swt.

Of course we should only ask to Allah but when to prophet Muhammad , it is not call asking it is called wasila which mean even they pray to Allah on behalf of us or for us.

May Allah swt guide us in right path ameen.