# What is the meaning of Shafa'ah (Sunni view)?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, sunni, terminology, shafaah

There is some narration from Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) installed in Masjid an Nabawi in Madinah, justified as "Sahih"(=Correct) or "Hassan"(=Well) in different Sunni references:

> النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏:‏ ‏ "‏ **شَفَاعَتِي** لأَهْلِ الْكَبَائِرِ مِنْ أُمَّتِي ‏"‏
>
> The Prophet (PBUH) said: My intercession (*shafa'ah*) will be for those of my people who have committed major sins. [Sunan Abi Dawud 4739](http://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/42/144), [Jami at-Tirmidhi 2435](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/726170), and also [2436](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/726180).

What is the idea of Sunni brothers about "Shafa'ah"? Who can do "Shafa'ah"? Is it Shirk to ask prophet's Shafa'ah?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shafa'ah means asking for forgiveness, Prophet Mohammad and Mala'eka can do shafa'ha, and no , it is not shirk , as there is this Hadith that tells us that there is a Doa' said after Azan , if we said it , we receive prophet's Mohammad shafa'ah . So basically , saying the Doa' is asking for the shafa'ah which is not shirk.
As for others who can shafa'ah :

> شفاعة الملائكة ثابتة بقوله تعالى(وكم من ملك فى الموات لاتغنى شفاعتهم
>   شيئا إلا من بعد أن يأذن الله لمن يشاء ويرضى) فى السنة اخرج ابن ماجه
>   والبرازوالبيهقى عن (النبى صلى الله عليه وسلم (يشفغ يوم القيامة
>   الانبياء,ثم العلماء,ثم الشهداء)

And this a part of the holy Qur'an telling us that the mala'eka (angels) can do shafa'ah. A narration telling us that prophets then scientists then martyrs can also do shafa'ah

Comment: +1 brother, thanks. Could you please provide more references? Also is there any narration that other people (i.e. other prophets, martyrs, etc) can do Shafa'ah?

Comment: I have references but they are in arabic, http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B4%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%A9

Comment: شفاعة الملائكة ثابتة بقولهتعالى(وكم من ملك فى الموات لاتغنى شفاعتهم شيئا إلا من بعد أن يأذن الله لمن يشاء ويرضى)
فى السنة اخرج ابن ماجه والبراز والبيهقى عن النبى صلى الله عليه وسلم (يشفغ يوم القيامة الانبياء,ثم العلماء,ثم الشهداء)
and this a part of the holy qura'n telling us that the mala'eka (angels) can do shafa'ah.
A narration telling us that prophets then scientists then martyrs can also do shafa'ah

Comment: @AbdelrahmanEsmat Brother please complete your answer with your comments and I would be happy to mark it accepted